# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS system-install and restore

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive, ssd

I am moving my laptop workstation from a 2 TByte spinning harddrive to a 4 TByte SSD and then want to restore the /home /opt /usr/local and any other non-standard directories and files to the new drive.  Will the following work?

1. Produce on the existing system a bootable image of the current 22.04.1 ISO file by `sudo dd if=ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb` assuming that the USB storage device is at /dev/sdb
2. Physically remove the existing hard drive and physically install the SSD (with appropriate antistatic precations -- grounded mat, grounded wrist, battery and mains power adapter removed, etc.).

2.1 Reassemble, etc.

3. Attach the bootable USB medium onto the computer, boot from the USB.
4. Install 22.04.1 onto the new SSD that physically is in the laptop.
5. Repeat step (2) above, but physically reinstalling the old previous 2 TB hard drive, and reboot.
6. Using a SSD to USB physical adapter, mount the SSD as a USB device on the machine.

6.1 Question:  will the 2TB system that uses "traditional" partitions be able to access the new 4TB drive or will some special command or other trick be needed?  If so, a simple workaround is to tar.gz each directory (e.g., /home) onto a 2TB USB drive mounted on the "old" system and then un-tar once the SSD is physically re-installed.

7. `cp -prf` each old directory over the new directories for /usr/local , /home , /opt and the like.  If 6.1 requires a tar, use the new system to un-tar the old tar.gz of each such directory onto the new system, replacing existing files (all from a 22.04LTS system). Note that system files such as the boot required files will not be touched.
8. Using `chown -R` and `chgrp -R` as root, change all UIDs of files to the ones of the current install if these are different (e.g., if user x has a different UID between the old system and what the Ubuntu installer generated for the new system).

Will the above work?

Comment: In theory yes but it is a lot more steps than I would believe you need.  The copy of files can be done between 1 and 2 onto a 2nd USB flash drive large enough and you would not need the HDD anymore. 5 and 6 would not be needed. " if user x has a different UID"  admin will be 1000 on both machines.